# Docusign Print & Sign Option- Multiple uploads

Tags: docusignapi

As a Docusign Administrator you have the ability to enable the 'Print and Sign' option for end users who wish to manually print the documents, sign, and then upload or fax them in/to docusign. My question is if the end user selects the upload option, it appears that you are only allowed to upload a single document. We have a requirement where in addition to signing the document and uploading it, the end user is required to upload additional documentation. Is there a way to allow the end user to upload multiple attachments when using the 'Print & Sign/ Upload' options?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thank you for using DocuSign! Please upvote all useful answers, including those to others' questions. And PLEASE check (accept) the best answer to your own questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Customer has opted for Print and Sign then DocuSign downloads the Document as a single PDF. Then it is expected by Signer to sign that PDF and upload the document back to DocuSign. So there is no scenario where Signer has to upload multiple attachments to DocuSign if opting for Print and Sign.

The setting which Drew referred in his post applies if customer does everything electronically and you have a Signer Attachment on the document which gives option to the signer to upload multiple documents at the time of electronic Signing.

Comment: Thanks Amit! do you happen to know if it is possible via the API's to distinguish whether a 'recipient' has used this feature to sign vs the digital method?

Comment: Yes, via API or DS Connect (recommended) you need to check document name, if its uploaded using Print and Sign option then DocuSign adds a document to the envelope with name like `Signed-on-Paper_........`

Answer (score 1):

There's an account setting for this under Go to Admin > Sending Settings > *Allow signers to add multiple attachments per field*.